# Mysql select cells that contain a string from another row's cell

Tags: mysql, select

Hello I've been looking all over and haven't found my answer. I am trying to make `mysql` select all rows that contain a certain string from another row

**For example:**

i

```
d | item | info
1 | circle    | red|blue
2 | square    | green|yellow
3 | triangle    | red|yellow
4 | rectangle    | blue|gray
```

---

```
 SELECT item FROM table WHERE info REGEXP (info from id 1)
```

Would return:

```
triangle, rectangle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a value from a column as a value in an expression, you have to write a `SELECT` query in parentheses.

```
SELECT item
FROM table
WHERE info REGEXP (SELECT info FROM table WHERE id = 1)
```

Or you can use a JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.item
FROM table AS t1
JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.info REGEXP t2.info
WHERE t2.id = 1
```